# Is it possible to connect a Nintendo DS screen to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: lcd

Is it possible to connect a Nintendo DS screen to a Raspberry Pi without the touch capability, or should I just buy another TFT?

Comment: It is possible, though the time it would take would be enormous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the pinout of the DS screen, there isn's a controller for the display, it appears to be a parallel RGB display. It would be a significant task to design a driver for it to be able to attach to a RasPi.